# Way to refactor multiple find methods in cucumber/capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, cucumber, capybara, bdd

Here's what I'm performing in my tests:

```
find('#instructors').find('.caption').find('h2').should have_content(full_name)
```

Is there a way to refactor it to just one find instead of three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you chain `find` methods, you are saying to find node A and within that find node B and within that find node C. As you are using CSS-selectors for each `find`, this is equivalent to using the CSS-selectors to search for descendants. Descendant searches are performed by simply adding a space between selectors.

The three `find` methods can be combined into a single `find` as:

```
find('#instructors .caption h2').should have_content('full_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking for something rather than interacting with it, you can use a matcher e.g.

```
 has_css('#instructors .caption h2', text: 'full_name')
```